# How to load page content from external api in jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to use external api and display its results (after json parsing) on my page, how to achive this? Maybe someone has working examples?

Edit:
For example, I would like to create page simple list of user repos using this api: http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/ (GET /users/:user/repos)

Comment: Can you provide the code you already have so far?

Comment: What are data you received from api..?

Comment: I have only base code from Getting started tutorial.

Comment: I edited post for better explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base level example that pulls from the flick API and inserts into the DOM.  http://jsfiddle.net/sgliser/tgzJC/2/

Comment: I see there only sample jQuery mobile page.

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot to save.  It's there now.